# Select Columns of non-delimited input file

Tags: input, offset

This is much easier than what I'm making it...

I have a non-delimited input file that I want to grab three columns from and output them to a new layout.  The input file is fixed length. I want to take the data from the following positions:
field1 - position 1 for 7 characters
field2 - position 13 for 50 characters
field3 - position 187 for 10 characters

I want my output file to be field1,field2,field3...comma delimited.

This is what I thought would work, but alas, it doesn't:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\mydata.txt) do (

set line=%%A

set var_id=!line:~0,7%!
set var_name=!line:~12,50%!
set var_amt=!line:~186,10%!

set ABC=!%var_id%%var_name%%var_amt%!

echo ABC

)
```